# JMockit: Verifying if a fake class method is called

Tags: java, unit-testing, jmockit

I currently have the following code for testing:

```
public class FakeClass extends MockUp<RealClass>
{
    @Mock
    public void doSomething() {
        ...
    }
}

void testHandleMetrics() {
    FakeClass fakeClass = new FakeClass();

    try {
        RealClassUser realClassUser = new RealClassUser();
        realClassUser.useDoSomethingMethod(); //This calls doSomething

        new VerificationInOrder() {
            {
                fakeClass.doSomething();
            }
        };
    } catch (Exception e) {
        fail("FAILED");
    }
}
```

Even if I put a failing combination in the VerificationsInOrder block (i.e. put another method), the test still passes. Is there something that I am not understanding with regards to the use of the Verifications block with fake classes?

Thank you!

Comment: You're not supposed to mix the faking and mocking APIs like this... Take some time to read the (quite short) [Getting started](http://jmockit.github.io/gettingStarted.html) page, it will clear things up.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you missed some points in mocking dependencies:

how does your *realClass* know about the mock?

This problem is usually addressed by *dependency injection*. That means your *realClass* does not instantiate the Dependency itself, but gets it injected from the outside, preferably as a constructor parameter.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK,   methods in verfication may not be involved.   FullVerificationInOrder is mre strickt.  I personally prefer expectation blocks  (See working sample here: https://github.com/ko5tik/jsonserializer/blob/master/src/test/de/pribluda/android/jsonmarshaller/JSONMarshallerTest.java)

And how your test class gets mocjed instance to perform calls in it?  At the moment,  it is not used at all

And I also prefer @Mocked annotation on parameters.

And you shall remove try-catch block from test -  not necessary here